# How to convert std::fmt::Arguments to a string?

Tags: rust

I would like to convert a `std::fmt::Arguments` to a string type. However, since the fields of `Arguments` are private, I cannot directly convert it into a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string):

```
fn example(a: std::fmt::Arguments) -> String {
    a.to_string()
}
```

Or use [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html):

```
fn example(a: std::fmt::Arguments) -> String {
    format!("{}", a)
}
```

Any of the other ways of using the formatting machinery will also work.

You could have figured this out yourself by looking at the [documentation for `Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) and making note of what methods and traits it implements:

```
impl<'a> Debug for Arguments<'a>
impl<'a> Clone for Arguments<'a>
impl<'a> Display for Arguments<'a>
impl<'a> Copy for Arguments<'a>
```

`Copy` and `Clone` aren't relevant here, but `Debug` and `Display` are.